# Jquery division between two numbers

Tags: javascript

Can you guys please help me in this matter :

I have two variable in jquery x and y , and I am doing a division between those two , and I let's say the result is 2.5 , but I only want to show 2 from 2.5 , how do I do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Truncate the decimal?  Round down?  Round up?

Perhaps just use Math.Floor:

var z = Math.Floor(x/y);

Comment: Somehow I'm reminded of [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: @Juhana my thoughts too.

Comment: $('jQuery').explosion();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're simply trying to truncate the decimal, use the following:

```
parseInt(2.5); // returns 2
```

If you're trying to round to the nearest integer, use the following:

```
Math.round(2.5); // returns 3
```

If you're trying to round down, use the following:

```
Math.floor(2.5); // returns 2
```

If you're trying to round up, use the following:

```
Math.ceil(2.5); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simply parseInt() within javascript on the result

```
var x = 12.5;
var y = ​5;

​var result = parseInt(x / y, 10); // the 2nd parameter signifies base-10
alert(result);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery at all for this.  Simply use JavaScript's [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method.